# Base64 to image conversion in python

Tags: base64

I want to decodea base64 string which is supposed to be an image, in python. The code is: 
import base64 
coded_string = '''b=Yis3dAX8CR9.........(ends with  ==)''' base64.b64decode(coded_string)

And output i get is: b"m\x88\xac\xdd\xd0\x17\xf0$}\xbfa\x8aR+\x08\x1a\xe46\x13=\x0b(\xcd\xa1\xd5\x08\x18\xc7\xc0\x7f\xed\x9d}\xc6\xee\xdc\x94\xd5\xa0u\x85\xe3\xae\xedwt\xc7\xbd\xf5\xf8\xb3\x11\x97\xca2\x1e]%N\x9f\x84\xf3\x0c\xa0\xe9\xb0\xe9/XB:n\x00\x159\xc8\x10`\x7f-\xad1\xbcI\xf4-\xce\x89\x83\xbe\xe0\xa0\x0f_\rz\x06o^\xb2\x15\xf6\x80<\xb4\xe3`i0\x02/S\xd4\x83\x13\xa0yxm\xe8\x9d;R\xce\xaa\x9d\x9a\x03Z\xf2\xd6g[\xa37D\xa9\x94P[\x01V6d%\xf1V\xb1\xba\xb6n\xa4\xbe\xf7=\xc9+pb\xecO\xbdDu\x1f\xed\x16\xce\xd9\xbe\x85S\xd2Q\xd1\xa3\xa7\xd78\x10\xc0/=\xd3\xe3\xae\x15\xa0\xfe\xecQ\x01u'\xb0\t/\x05\xae\xe9\x82\xcb\xcdF\xa3\x0e\xf3\xcb\xd1.Ic$\x16\xdcc\xaaC\x7f\xd6\x85\x8e\xe6\x90L\x08+\x80\xce\xdb\xbe\xcf\xe9j\x0c\xdc\x1a\xd0\xca\xa4\xddU[m\xf4\xd1\xf4\xde\xac\x0c{2\xaa\x10\xf3\x87\x8c"

Im not sure what to do with this output..and how to get an image as ouput or may be some understanble text. Please help.. Thank you.

Comment: What text would you expect to come from the representation of an image?

Comment: not sure abt it. Actually i have raw email data in a txt file that has email conversation along with the string which is said to be base64 string.. and its o/p is supposed to be an image, could be a text or something else as well

Comment: the string looks like this: one of the string looks like this:Subject;b=Yis3dAX8CR9v2GKUisIGuQ2Ez0LKM2h1QgYx8B/7Z19xu7clNWgdYXjru13dMe99fizEZfKMh5dJU6fhPMMoOmw6S9YQjpuABU5yBBgfy2tMbxJ9C3OiYO+4KAPXw16Bm9eshX2gDy042BpMAIvU9SDE6B5eG3onTtSzqqdmgNa8tZnW6M3RKmUUFsBVjZkJfFWsbq2bqS+9z3JK3Bi7E+9RHUf7RbO2b6FU9JR0aOn1zgQwC890+OuFaD+7FEBdSewCS8FrumCy81Gow7zy9EuSWMkFtxjqkN/1oWO5pBMCCuAztu+z+lqDNwa0Mqk3VVbbfTR9N6sDHsyqhDzh4w==" @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

Save the output to a file; open that file as you would an image file.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear, but you can do as below. Also, if you already have base64 string for an image, do not convert it to base64, instead use it directly.

PNG

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,base64 string here" />
```

Or

JPEG

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,base64 string here" />
```